# C++ use alias template declaration in different classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using, typename

I got three template classes ([Code in C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/7mros)) and an alias template `using AType = A<T1,T2>` defined in `A`. I would like to use the alias across the files where objects of `A` are being used.

So in `B` instead of writing:

`C<A<T1,T2>> c_object;`

I'd rather like to be able to write something like:

`C<typename AType> c_object;`

using the alias declared in `A`.

```
// A.h
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A{
    A();
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
using AType = A<T1,T2>;

// C.h
template<typename H>
// H = A<T1,T2>
class C{
    C();
};

// B.h
#include "A.h"
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B{
    B();
    // const C<A<T1,T2>>& GetC() const;
    const C<typename AType>& GetC() const;
private:
    C<typename AType> c_object;
};
```

Note the relations of the template parameters.

If `B` would only have one template parameter `G` like:

```
template<typename G>
class B{};
```

I could just do:

```
C<typename G::AType> c_object;
```

But since `B` actually has two, I can't figure out how that would work out. Or is entire problem usually solved in a different way?

Comment: What is G::AType? I am confused

Comment: Do you mean `C<AType<T1, T2>>`?

Comment: I'd love to simply write `C<AType> c_object;` as I have declared `using AType = A<T1,T2>`. If I'd like to write `C<<AType<T1, T2>> c_object;` I could skip the entire alias definition, which I don't want.

Comment: `AType` is still a template, so you have to specify the template parameters anyway.

Comment: What is T1 & T2. Your alias do nothing for you. It simply makes AType equivalent to A, so nothing has changed. Do you want using AType = A<int,float>?

Comment: @Klaus: As written `G` `could be a template parameter of `B` if it would only have one. So `G::AType` is a template specialization.

Comment: Can't see G here! So what is G::*????

Comment: @DummySenior: alias templates don't do some kind of implicit binding of template arguments. What you're asking for is not possible, you must specify the template arguments for `A`; T1 and T2 don't get passed on implicitly.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the point .. it's not possible to have an abbreviation of `A<T1,T2>` by `AType`.

Comment: The template type parameters T1 and T2 of B and the parameters T1 and T2 of A or AType are not related at all, the compiler cannot guess that you want them to be the same in the context of B. They are in a sense like function parameter names and are only valid within their respective template definition.

Comment: No! You can have AType as alias for A<int,float>. If not AType<int,float> is the same as A<int,float>. So I can't catch the point you want to solve!

Comment: The point is that my class `B` has lots of code and I wanted to improve code readability by using the abbreviation `AType` for `A<T1,T2>` and thought this might work since the template parameters are the same. But unfortunately, this doesn't work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead add a `using` to `B` for your `C` type:

```
#include "A.h"
template<class T1, class T2>
struct B{
    using C_type =  A<T1, T2>;
    B();
    // const C_type& GetC() const;
    const C_type& GetC() const;
private:
    C_type c_object;
};
```

Or could inject `A` into the template arguments for `B`, which would let the caller optionally change it:

```
#include "A.h"
template<class T1, class T2, template<class, class> class C_T = A<T1, T2>>
struct B{
    B();
    // const C_T& GetC() const;
    const C_T& GetC() const;
private:
    C_T c_object;
}
```

---

You misunderstand what template aliases are for. They simply make referring to some other template easier; they don't implicitly bind template arguments to be passed on (T1 and T2 don't get implicitly passed to `A` in your OP; the template arguments to A must be specified).

You could simplify writing a `C` type templated for `A` using a template alias:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
using C_A = C<A<T1, T2>>;
```

And then you could use `C_A<T1, T2>` in `B`. This may be more flexible if you need a `C` templated on `A` in more than one location. However, what I wrote above may be preferable; this was only for demonstrated purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `AType` isn't a type; it's a template template type.

Your code compile if you write `C` as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class>
class C 
 { C(); };
```

and pass `AType` in this way

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class B
 {
      B();
      const C<AType>& GetC() const;
   private:
      C<AType> c_object;
 };
```

but I don't understand what do you want to do with `C` and `AType`

**-- EDIT --**

Klaus say

> In your posted code you write `C<AType> c_objectwhich` is invalid as using AType = A;`. I can't see the place where you put any type to aliased template AType. So your posted code makes no sense as T1 and T2 are unused.

My answer: I suppose that my posted code "makes no sense as T1 and T2 are unused", because I didn't understand the sense of the original code.

But you say my code "is invalid".

The following is my code that use `C<AType> c_objectwhich` and `using AType = A<T1,T2>;`. Please, say to me where is invalid and which error you get compiling it.

```
template <typename, typename>
class A { A(); };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using AType = A<T1,T2>;

template <template <typename...> class>
class C { C (); };

template <typename, typename>
class B
 {
      B();

      const C<AType> & GetC () const;
   private:

      C<AType> c_object;
 };

int main()
 { }


template <typename, typename>
class A { A(); };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using AType = A<T1,T2>;

template <template <typename...> class>
class C { C (); };

template <typename, typename>
class B
 {
      B();

      const C<AType> & GetC () const;
   private:

      C<AType> c_object;
 };

int main()
 { }
```

Comment: Where class B uses T1 & T2? It is not implicitly passes T1 and T2 to AType... As this, B is defined as template, but parameters are unused. So what is that good for?

Comment: @Klaus - no; if you define `AType` as `template<typename T1, typename T2> using AType = A<T1,T2>;` you're saying that `AType` need two template types to be a type; you have to use in as (by example) `AType<int, long>`; you can write `C<AType<T1, T2>> c_object;` (if `C` must receive a type`, but `AType` (without template arguments) isn't a type

Comment: In your posted code you write ` C<AType> c_object`which is invalid as `using AType = A<T1,T2>;`. I can't see the place where you put any type to aliased template AType. So your posted code makes no sense as T1 and T2 are unused.

Comment: @Klaus - I've transcribed a full compiled code in my answer; please, explain what do you mean with "your posted code [...] is invalid".

Comment: It is useless, as you class B did not need any template parameters. And AType is passed to C, but not used there. So I can't see the place where AType will be instantiated. And as AType alias A it is also useless, because it change nothing. A is same as AType. So what all the stuff is good for? Your previously code contains T1 and T2 as template parms for B for nothing as now B needs 2 template parms which are unused. What is that good for? The "invalid code" comment was corrected before you post your changes!

Comment: @Klaus - yes: useless; but the meaning of my code was show you the difference between a "template" and a "template template" argument; and explain you that in your original code problem was that `AType` was a "template template" argument (ps: the "invalid code" part is still here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156553/discussion-between-klaus-and-max66).

Comment: Sorry, can't use chat here. Website blocked by our firewall... sorry! To explain how to use a template as template parameter you can explain it even better without using any unused template parameters! And your answer should result in using AType alias. So i believe your answer has no content in relation to the OP question, because T1,T2 is not passed to AType. Simply that...

Comment: @Klaus - sorry, I've confused you with the OP; but the OP has written " I can't figure out how that would work out", so (I suppose) he has problem understanding the difference between "template" and "template template" argument. I've tried show this difference. It's can be be done better? Sure. But this don't make my code "invalid".